# How to disable animations in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material-5

I have used angular material version: 5.2.1

And wanted to know how to disable their animations,
especially the matDialog.

I have tried @.disabled but no luck.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Any specific reason ?

Comment: client's preference. no fancy animation on modal

Comment: There is a feature request being tracked here in the material repository regarding disabling only the dialog animations [Add possibility to turn off animation of dialog enter/exit](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3616)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `NoopAnimationsModule` by angular material

```
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NoopAnimationsModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Or if you want to remove transition on some specific components you can do it via CSS like this

```
.mat-dialog{ transition: none; }
```

Comment: that's it? just import NoopAnimationsModule?

Comment: yes, for more information on this module you can refer this https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Works, but you should mention to import in main app module.

Comment: I don't feel to import in `app.module` if you are using lazzy loaded modules isn't it @EdgarQuintero?

Comment: if you import 'NoopAnimationsModule' then spinners won't work also.
.mat-dialog transition does nothing.

Comment: Not tested this, might be an open issue in the version you are checking.

Answer (score 3):

The approved answer does not work and is not consistent with Angular docs, at least since Angular 6.
To disable animations in Angular 6 to 13, [from the official doc](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#disabling-all-animations), use:

```
// In app.component.ts

import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('@.disabled')
  public animationsDisabled = true;  // Set to true to disable animations
}
```

This is useful for end-to-end (E2E) testing.