# How to disable mat-spinner out animation

Tags: angular, typescript

The Angular Material spinner that i have implemented has got an animation out which makes it go down before vanishing. Is there a way to unable this animation?
This is the code: I tried with the keyframes but it doesn't work.

```
<mat-spinner style="margin: auto; margin-top: 10%"></mat-spinner>

  @keyframes slideDown {
    0% {}
    100% {
        transform: translateY(20%);
    }
}

.cdk-overlay-pane {
    transform: translateY(-250%);
    animation: slideDown 0.5s forwards 0s ease-in;
}

.cdk-overlay-container>* {
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: The code must work on IE

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385136/how-to-disable-animations-in-angular-material

Answer (score 1):

Add "**BrowserAnimationsModule**" in your @NgModule imports array, and remove **"NoopAnimationsModule"** if you have it there.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [..],
imports: [
    ..
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ..
]
})
```

Comment: I already have the BrowserAnimationsModule there and there is no NoopAnimationsModule too.

Comment: @ScottThushy Please add more source code in the question.