# how to open angular material popup(matDialog) without any animations

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
 public openForgotDialog(): void {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.width = '450px';
    dialogConfig.panelClass ="dialog-container";
    const dialog = this.matDialog.open(ForgotComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

like this i'm calling a method to open a matdialog popup, without a animation popup has to open, crazy requirement from client

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385258/3520837 ?

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disable-animations

```
 <div #dialogContainer [@.disabled]="true"></div>
```